# Python .reverse() and .extend()

Tags: python, reverse, extend, mirror

I'm a beginner in Python. I try to create a list from 1~5 then print out the reverse list and combine them like `[1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1]` and here is my working.

```
num1 = list(range(1,6))
num2 = num1.reverse()
print(num1)
print(num2)
print(num1.extend(num2))
```

Output of num1 is reverse `[5,4,3,2,1]`. Output of num2 is `None` and the extend function not working. How `.reverse()` and `.extend()` really work?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html "list.reverse() Reverse the elements of the list in place.". The key thing here is "in place".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.reverse()
```

does the reversal in-place - so your original list is reversed. And also, the `reverse()` method returns `None`

Hence your `num1` get reversed & `num2` is `None`.

Similarly, `extend` also modifies the argument list & returns `None`

To make this work:

```
num1 = list(range(1,6))
num2 = num1[::-1]
print(num1)
print(num2)
num1.extend(num2)
print(num1)
```

Gives:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.reverse()` does not return anything; it mutates `num1` to be its reverse.

`list.extend()` takes in another list, and adds all of the elements from that list to the list you are calling on. Since `list.reverse()` does not return anything, num2 becomes `None`. So, you are extending num2 with `none` which won't result in any changes to num1.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for a description of some of the list methods.